# How to split string with square brackets and commas to columns and rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, split

I want to split strings like: `[[6, 10, 11, 16], [0.4444444444444445, 53.0, 7.555555555555555, 5.111111111111111]]`

to output

```
id       value
---------------------------
6        0.4444444444444445
10       53.0
11       7.555555555555555
16       5.111111111111111
```

Number of 'ids' in the string varies but there is always value for an 'id'.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: It's actually Maria-database and I'm using HeidiSQL to manage it.

Comment: Which version of Mariadb?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using a stored procedure which chops up the string, creates a (temporary) table, stores the result in said table and returns the table content using a `SELECT` statement.

**However it is unlikely that this is an efficient approach** - it will be time consuming to write and execution time will not be good, creating a bottle neck if you pass it a lot of data or if is called repeatedly.

A simpler approach - and the route I would follow - is to do this in your favorite programming language and then store the result in the database. 
Alternatively the output of your code could be a query with `UNION` which would return the desired data structure. Essentially the task is to transpose a two dimensional array and structure the output. If it is not overly large, this would be fast and efficient and could be used as a subquery if you need to combine it with other data.

To give you and idea, the output could be as follows:

```
SELECT 6 AS id, 0.4444444444444445 AS value
UNION ALL SELECT 10, 53.0
UNION ALL SELECT 11,7.555555555555555
UNION ALL SELECT 16, 5.111111111111111
```

Put to practical use:

```
SELECT 
   sub.id,
   sub.value,
   info.someFieldFromAnotherTable
FROM
   (SELECT 6 AS id, 0.4444444444444445 AS value
    UNION ALL SELECT 10, 53.0
    UNION ALL SELECT 11,7.555555555555555
    UNION ALL SELECT 16, 5.111111111111111
   ) AS sub
   INNER JOIN otherInfoTable info ON info.id = sub.id
```